# Can data source be changed for OBIEE 12C RPD?

Tags: obiee

I'm new to OBIEE. I have version 12.2.1.4 installed on a Linux server. I installed the client tools on my Windows PC. Using the Administration tool I created a simple RPD which uses only two tables. For this I had to first create an ODBC DSN to connect to my DB/2 database.

Next, I uploaded the RPD to the OBIEE server using the datamodel cli tool. When I go to the http://hostname:9502/analytics page and select to create a new analysis, it shows me the name of the repository and the two tables. I selected a couple of columns and clicked on the Results tab.

At this point, I get an error message: `ODBC error state: IM002 code: 0 message: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

I had used the em console to create a JNDI connection to DB/2. But, from the message it seems that it is trying to use the ODBC connection that was used when creating the RPD on my PC.

How do I change the connection that the server is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needs to be able to reach the data source. EM JNDI connections have nothing to do with it, but rather the server (server OS - not the application) has to reach the source.

You need to update your ODBC settings on the Linux server: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2570997.1

Comment: Naturally, the OBIEE server can and does reach the data source which is how I created the JNDI connection. Do you mean that the JNDI connection won't work and I need to create an ODBC connection to the database from the server?

Comment: EM JNDI connections have nothing to do with RPD connections to the data. Yes the server needs to be able to talk to the DB via ODBC.